# Cannot find Vietnamese (Unikey) in text input although ibus-unikey is installed

Tags: ibus, input-language, input-method

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I installed Vietnamese Input Method Engine for ibus using Unikey Engine on Application Center.

But when I open text entry and try to add it, Vietnamese appears but Vietnamese (Unikey) does not appear.

I tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ibus` and restarted my laptop but it still does not appear.

[image: Image 1: installed from application center]

[image: Image 2: Unikey not appear]

Comment: Is **IBus** the selected input method system in Language Support?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. reinstall ibus (this would fix any error or missing files)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ibus
   ```
2. restart ibus

   ```
   ibus restart
   ```
3. go to Preferences and Vietnamese should appear.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

We have to enable ibus-unikey after installed it.

> #### Step 1:
>
> - Open **System Settings**/**Language Support**
> - In **Language** tab/**keyboard input method system** choose ***Ibus***
> - Install Vietnamese if you did not.
>
> #### Step 2:
>
> - reboot
>
> #### Step 3:
>
> - Open **System Settings**/**Text Entry**
> - Hit '**+**' to add the "***Vietnamese(Unikey)(IBus)***"
> - ( Make sure the "*Show current input source in the menu bar*" was ticked )

After reboot, you'll see the Unikey option.
Hope this help you and the others !!

Chúc bạn thành công.